# how can i make a graph in javascript using c3.js

Tags: javascript, html, graph, c3.js

i am trying to make a graph in javascript using chart.js. i have this code below but when i run it the page is empty.
this code is an example that ive seen in the internet, and it says that it doesn't recognize the "generate" function in the javascrpt file (it doesnt throws an exception or an error, just marks the "generate" word in gray and doesn't shows anything when i run the code)

this is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


<head>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id ="myChart"></div>
<script><script src="lol.js"></script></script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the js code:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
            ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
        ]
    }
});

setTimeout(function () {
    chart.load({
        columns: [
            ['data1', 230, 190, 300, 500, 300, 400]
        ]
    });
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function () {
    chart.load({
        columns: [
            ['data3', 130, 150, 200, 300, 200, 100]
        ]
    });
}, 1500);

setTimeout(function () {
    chart.unload({
        ids: 'data1'
    });
}, 2000);
```

how can i fix that? i need to make a graph to my project with javascript and i trying to find out a way how. thanks!

Comment: You're including chart.js but using [C3.js](https://c3js.org/) code?

Comment: oops, didn't realiused i was copying the wrong html file. changing it now

Comment: i will innclude c3 one sec

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing the `bindto` part of C3's initialization code:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
  bindto: '#myChart',  // <---- here
  data: {
    columns: [
      ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
      ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
    ]
  }
});
```

Comment: its still empty page

Comment: `<script><script src="lol.js"></script></script>` is invalid. Try replacing it with `<script src="lol.js"></script>`. Also check the browser's console for errors/warnings.